# Can xQueueReceive fail when xTicksToWait = portMAX_DELAY?

Tags: c, error-handling, real-time, message-queue, freertos

Let's imagine I have this kind of event loop :

```
MyType_t object;
while(true) {
    xQueueReceive(QHandle, &object, portMAX_DELAY);
    doSomething(object);
}
```

The documentation (https://www.freertos.org/a00118.html) stipulates :

> If INCLUDE_vTaskSuspend is set to ‘1’ then specifying the block time
> as portMAX_DELAY will cause the task to block indefinitely (without a
> timeout).

To me, this means that it will always wait until it can receive a value, which means it can never fail to receive a value, but I may be wrong.

Is it necessary to check for `xQueueReceive` failure ? If it is, what are the failure modes ?

Comment: Regardless of how likely it is to fail, it's always a good idea to check. The docs mention that it'll block indefinitely if `INCLUDE_vTaskSuspend` is 1, but if the code was used somewhere where that isn't the case, it would presumably fail if things aren't available after the maximum delay. Is there any downside to checking for failure? Sure it'll very slightly increase code size (probably by only a couple instructions), but it's always a good idea.

Comment: Well, checking for the include can be done at compile time. I agree that error checking may not be costly (size-wise and performance-wise), but what is really important to me is the failure modes. I need to understand them for error handling

Comment: Nothing shown on that page of documentation says anything about a case other than simply not receiving something. It wouldn't surprise me if it is simply a case of it either receiving a message or never receiving a message. Have you read through the source? As a side note, excluding a check by checking a compile-time define seems like a sloppy way of doing things. You often have to assume that something is a black box (though you have the source here). What FreeRTOS was compiled with different flags than your code?

Answer (score 1):

Suspending a task allows truly indefinite blocking on a queue. Otherwise it returns with timeout after `portMAX_DELAY` ticks which is usually very, very long.
If the slightly increased code size setting `INCLUDE_vTaskSuspend` to 1 doesn’t matter I’d propose to do so.
Although receiving from a queue with indefinite timeout can’t fail it’s good style to check the return code.